# Object.is vs ===

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I stumbled upon a code example which was using this comparison:

```
var someVar = 0;
Object.is(false, someVar); //Returns false
```

I know `false == 0` will be `true` that's why we have `===`.

How is `Object.is` different from `===`?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

`===` is called strict comparison operator in JavaScript. `Object.is` and strict comparison operator behave exactly the same except for `NaN` and `+0/-0`.

From MDN:

> `Object.is()` method is not the same as being equal according to the `===` operator. The `===` operator (and the `==` operator as well) treats the number values -0 and +0 as equal and treats `Number.NaN` as not equal to `NaN`.

Code below highlights the difference between `===` and `Object.is()`.

```
console.log(+0 === -0); //true
console.log(Object.is(+0, -0)); //false

console.log(NaN === NaN); // false
console.log(Object.is(NaN, NaN)); //true

console.log(Number.NaN === Number.NaN); // false
console.log(Object.is(Number.NaN, Number.NaN)); // true

console.log(NaN === Number.NaN); // false
console.log(Object.is(NaN, Number.NaN)); // true
```

[image]

You can find more examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is).

**Note**: `Object.is` is part of the ECMAScript 6 proposal and is not widely supported yet (e.g. it's not supported by any version of Internet Explorer or many older versions of other browsers). However you can use a polyfill for non-ES6 browsers which can be found in link given above.

Comment: The first line of the answer should be "They behave exactly the same except for NaN and +0 and -0", probably.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Good suggestion. Makes answer easier to read. Cheers.

Comment: @humble.rumble this was discussed at length - static methods are simpler - they don't have context issues or primitive issues. For example in your example I'd expect _false_ but newbies to JS would expect _true_ since doing `.x` on a string boxes it into a `String` object (and not a string primitive value) and the comparison would be between an object and a string - this is very subtle and is a pitfall - statics avoid these issues, static methods  are simpler and easier to use.

Comment: @humble.rumble For comparing DOM nodes, there is already such a method, see [isEqualNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode). Example: `document.createElement('div').isEqualNode(document.createElement('div')) === true`

Comment: So this is good, because we didn't have enough equality operators in JS o_O

Comment: 2017 Update: Object.is() is now widely supported in all major browsers.

Comment: Can anyone enlighten me regarding when you'd want comparison between `-0` and `+0` to be `false`? To me it seems like you'd want those to be counted as equal in practically all cases.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh did you create this comparison table at your own?

Answer (score 62):

`Object.is` uses the specification's [SameValue algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-samevalue), whereas `===` uses the [Strict Equality Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-strict-equality-comparison). A note on the Strict Equality Algorithm calls out the difference:

> This algorithm differs from the SameValue Algorithm...in its treatment of signed zeroes and NaNs.

Note that:

- `NaN === NaN` is false, but `Object.is(NaN, NaN)` is true
- `+0 === -0` is true, but `Object.is(+0, -0)` is false
- `-0 === +0` is true, but `Object.is(-0, +0)` is false

JavaScript has *at least* four kinds of "equality":

- "Loose" (`==`), where the operands will be coerced to try to make them match. The rules are [clearly specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), but non-obvious. (`"" == 0` is `true`; `"true" == true` is `false`, ...).
- "Strict" (`===`), where operands of differing types will not be coerced (and will not be equal), but see note above about `NaN` and positive and negative zero.
- SameValue - as listed above (used by `Object.is`).
- SameValueZero - like `SameValue` except `+0` and `-0` are the same instead of different (used by `Map` for keys, and by `Array.prototype.includes`).

There's also *object equivalence*, which isn't provided by the language or runtime itself, but is usually expressed as: The objects have the same prototype, same properties, and their property values are the same (by some reasonable definition of "the same").

---

[SameValue algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-samevalue):

> - If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> - If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>   - If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true.
>   - If x is +0 and y is -0, return false.
>   - If x is -0 and y is +0, return false.
>   - If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>   - Return false.
> - Return SameValueNonNumber(x, y).

...where [SameValueNonNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-samevaluenonnumber) is:

> - Assert: Type(x) is not Number.
> - Assert: Type(x) is the same as Type(y).
> - If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> - If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> - If Type(x) is String, then
>
>   - If x and y are exactly the same sequence of code units (same length and same code units at corresponding indices), return true; otherwise, return false.
> - If Type(x) is Boolean, then
>
>   - If x and y are both true or both false, return true; otherwise, return false.
> - If Type(x) is Symbol, then
>
>   - If x and y are both the same Symbol value, return true; otherwise, return false.
> - Return true if x and y are the same Object value. Otherwise, return false.

---

[Strict Equality Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-strict-equality-comparison):

> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    - If x is NaN, return false.
>    - If y is NaN, return false.
>    - If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    - If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
>    - If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
>    - Return false.
> 3. Return SameValueNonNumber(x, y).

Answer (score 2):

```js
Object.is = function(v1, v2){
  //test for `-0`
  if(v1 === 0 && v2 === 0) {
    return 1 / v1 === 1 / v2;
  }
  
  //test for `NaN`
  if(v1 !== v1) {
    return v2 !== v2;
  }
  
  //everything else
  return v1 === v2;
}
```

The above is the polyfill function to show how `Object.is` works, for anyone who are interested to know. A reference to [You-Don't-Know-JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md)

Answer (score 2):

### Summary:

The `Object.is()` function takes 2 values as arguments and returns true if the 2 given values are exact the same, otherwise it will return false.

### Why do we need this?

You might think, we already have strict equality (checks type + value) checking in javascript with the `===` operator, why do we need this function? Well strict equality isn't sufficient in some cases and they are the following:

```js
console.log(NaN === NaN);   // false
console.log(-0 === +0);     // true
```

`Object.is()` helps us by being able to compare these values to see if they are similar, something the strict equality operator cannot do.

```js
console.log(Object.is(NaN, NaN));  // true
console.log(Object.is(-0, 0));     // false
console.log(Object.is(+0, +0));    // true
console.log(Object.is(+0, -0));    // false
```

Answer (score 1):

`===` is considered a strict comparison and will return a boolean indicating whether or not the operands are of the same type and the contents match.

`Object.is` behaves the same as `===` expect for the +/- 0 and NaN cases

```js
console.log({} === {}) // false
console.log(Object.is({}, {})) // false

console.log(1 === 1) // true
console.log(Object.is(1, 1)) // true

console.log(NaN === NaN) // false
console.log(Object.is(NaN, NaN)) // true

console.log(+0 === -0) // true
console.log(Object.is(+0, -0)) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, they are similar, but `Object.is` is smarter and more accurate...

Let's look at this...

```
+0 === -0 //true
```

But this is not fully right as it ignores `-` and `+` before...

Now we use:

```
Object.is(+0, -0) //false
```

As you see, this is more accurate to compare.

Also in case of `NaN` that works more like correct, as consider any `NaN` the same.